# Can you set all dummy indices equal to each other?

Tags: notation, tensor-calculus

According to the Einstein summation convention, can you set all dummy indices within a same expression equal to each other? Example, if both α and β are dummy indices in a same expression can you set α=β?

Comment: What? Please give an example.

Comment: What's a dummy index??? Which indices you sum over determines what you are calculating.

Comment: You can replace the **name** of **one** dummy index **name** (both appearances, a dummy appears twice) on **one** side of an equals sign with **any name** currently not being used on that side of the equals sign. By repeated use of this rule you can swap dummy indices (to swap alpha and beta first rename alpha into unused-name then rename beta into alpha then rename unused-name into beta). And by swapping and/or renaming on one side of an equals sign enough times you might be able to make a dummy on one side match a dummy on the other side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking you cannot equate an arbitrary pair of indices with one another.

You need to prove that the two indices carry the same physical meaning before making them equal in an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know Alpha and Beta are equal, you cannot set them equal just because they are dummy. And, Oclelo7 is right. We need to see your example and the physical meaning of your indices. Thanks,